# How to Proof that the quadratic equation is continuous in the Real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, quadratics

Intuitively is obvious that an equation of the form $ax^2 +bx+c$ is continuous for all real numbers because it does not have any indeterminacy.
But I need a more formal proof

Comment: What do you mean by "indeterminacy"?

Comment: As you can see in [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/formal-proofs/info), the tag [tag:formal-proofs] is for proofs in various formal systems, such as [natural deduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction) or [Hilbert system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system). I do not assume that this is what you are after. I have changed the tag, feel free to edit them again if you can find better ones or if some of the tags I've added does not fit your question.

Answer (score 4):

### Outline

You can prove the following theorems about continuity:

1. constant is continuous
2. identity is continuous
3. sum of continuous functions is continuous
4. product of continuous functions is continuous

Then just use 1-4 to prove that $ax^2+bx+c$ is continuous.

---

### 1. Constant is continuous

We say that $\forall r \in \Bbb R: \displaystyle \lim_{x \to r} f(x) = f(r)$ where $f(x) = C$ for a constant $C$.

That is, $\forall r \in \Bbb R: \forall \varepsilon > 0 : \exists \delta > 0: \forall x \in \Bbb R: |x-r| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(r)| < \varepsilon$.

Letting $\delta = 1$ solves the problem.

---

### 2. Identity is continuous

We say that $\forall r \in \Bbb R: \displaystyle \lim_{x \to r} f(x) = f(r)$ where $f(x) = x$ for all real number $x$.

That is, $\forall r \in \Bbb R: \forall \varepsilon > 0 : \exists \delta > 0: \forall x \in \Bbb R: |x-r| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(r)| < \varepsilon$.

Letting $\delta = \varepsilon$ solves the problem.

---

### 3. Sum of continuous functions is continuous

We say that $\forall r \in \Bbb R: \displaystyle \lim_{x \to r} f(x) + g(x) = f(r) + g(r)$ where $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions.

That is, $\forall r \in \Bbb R: \forall \varepsilon > 0 : \exists \delta > 0: \forall x \in \Bbb R: |x-r| < \delta \implies |f(x)+g(x)-f(r)-g(r)| < \varepsilon$.

Plug in $\dfrac\varepsilon2$ to the expressions of $f$ and $g$ to obtain $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ respectively, then take the minimum.

---

### 4. Product of continuous functions is continuous

We say that $\forall r \in \Bbb R: \displaystyle \lim_{x \to r} f(x) g(x) = f(r) g(r)$ where $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions.

That is, $\forall r \in \Bbb R: \forall \varepsilon > 0 : \exists \delta > 0: \forall x \in \Bbb R: |x-r| < \delta \implies |f(x) g(x) - f(r) g(r)| < \varepsilon$.

This is left to the reader as an exercise.